# FileRead in java with a >32 bit offset

Tags: java, inputstream

Both InputStream and FileReader in java the maximum offset value is (I assume) that of the max value of a signed 32bit int. But what If I'm trying to read contents beyond this 8GB limit?

Comment: The `offset` value is the offset *into the read buffer.* The file position is established by `InputStream.skip()` or `RandomAccessFile.seek(),` both of which take `long` parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `skip()` (for both FileReader and InputStream) accepts a `long` rather than an `int` so your offset would be limited to a 64 signed integer, which is already sufficient for a real-life file size.

The size of the offset is rather limited by the filesystem you're working with or the underlaying stream; for instance: a FAT32 filesystem can't have a file system bigger than 2G

Comment: I guess actually reading all of the javadoc would help in retrospec :\ Thank you for your help. Well accept once 8 minutes have passed.